# Comparing 2 columns to check how far is the prediction from real values R

Tags: r, statistics

I have 2 columns

```
exp predicted
20      24
10      12
35      36
22      23
21      33
50      51
40      39
33      32
150     148
88      89
12      15
```

and need to compare this two columns to get a score to match them, to see how far is the prediction from the real values, obviously I can not use simply

```
exp == predict 
and 
mean(exp == predict)
```

sins not looking for an exact match, 
What would be the most efficient way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many ways of comparing prediction and observation and you should read up on them. Two common ways include R2 and RMSE:

```
library(caret)
R2( predict , exp )
RMSE( predict , exp )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply David, so If i understood it right R2 gives some like degrees of freedom in this case between this two columns?

Comment: it's a complex topic that belongs more on cross-validated, but you can read up on it on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient